# df.sort_values().groupby results in a column length issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the original table:

```
   A  B  C  E
0  1  1  5  4
1  1  1  1  1
2  3  3  8  2
```

I wanted to apply some aggregate functions to this table which I did with:

```
df.sort_values('C').groupby(['A', 'B'], sort=False).agg({'C': 'sum', 'E': 'last'})
```

My new table looks like this:

```
A B  C  E
1 1  6  4
3 3  8  2
```

When I measure the column lenght of the original VS the modified table with this command `len(df.columns)` , the results differ though.

The original table returns 4 columns and the modified table returns 2 columns.

My question: Why did this happen and how can I get to return 4 columns with the modified table?